# How do I create a table to get unique values in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to make a new table of just the distinct organisations which have a `1` under the column `Dup`, but I keep getting duplicate organisations, how do I go about this?

[image]

For example it should just show:

```
Organisation
Royal Marsden Hospital
```

Comment: Are you trying to define a new table with a single column? If not, what are you trying to do with this column?

Comment: Yes, my mistake I need to create another table to show the distinct names of organisations which have a duplicate, so just a list of organisations with a 1 under `dup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DISTINCT` function and apply a filter for `[Dup] = 1`.

```
Dup Orgs = CALCULATETABLE ( DISTINCT ( Table1[Organisation] ), Table1[Dup] = 1 )
```

Comment: CALCULATETABLE! the penny dropped, it works now. Thanks